# 12V battery back-up system using a relay

Tags: relay, backup

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPAdyG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to use a 12V battery as a back up power source. I made this circuit but it doesn't work properly.

When the adapter is off the device (shown as a lamp) works on battery no problem, but when I plug in the wall adapter power goes off on the output and the relay switches and gets stuck to the adapter side until I disconnect the battery and then it switches back.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit should work.

It appears that you have wrongly wired the relay contacts as shown below.

[image]

Please cross-check and rewire.

Comment: This is not correct. It will parallel the power adapter and the battery and disconnect the load when the relay is engaged.

Comment: Exactly, @StarCat! And that is what the OP is reporting. His circuit should work. Apparently, he has wrongly wired it as shown above.

Comment: It might help if you add that explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to power your device from a battery or power adapter? Consider using a switched DC jack.  This will automatically disconnect the battery when you plug in the adapter.  No relay required.

See "Conductors in Dc Power Connectors" on this page: [how-to-select-a-dc-power-connector](https://www.cuidevices.com/blog/how-to-select-a-dc-power-connector)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping. It's not clear what you meant by the statement (which I deleted as it's meta, not part of the answer) when you said: "If my answer helps please mark it as an answer.". If you were asking the OP to *accept* your answer *if it helps* then no, that's not what *accepting* an answer means. As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an OP is encouraged to accept the **most** helpful answer (to them). As only one answer can be accepted per question, an OP *must not* accept an answer just because it's helpful, that's what an upvote is for. Any questions?

Comment: Noted.  "Please remember to accept the most helpful answer" is the terminology I was going for.  I often find that posters forget to accept answers.  It would not bother me except I'm trying to build minimum reputation level.